# C++ Builder 2009 Context Look Ahead Taking a Long Time

Tags: c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 2009 and find the context look ahead (Ctrl + space) to be taking a very long time.

My dev machine has nice hardware, and is running Win 7. Eclipse's look ahead is very quick.

My builder environment does have a lot of 3rd party components installed, however it should not take 13 seconds to display suggestions.

I'm looking for tips/suggestions on how to speed this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code insight is a feature that has a few problems.  It is quite slow, particularly in older releases of Builder C++.  Newer releases have gotten better, mostly due to the precompiler header wizard.

The trick to speedy code insight is to use precompiled headers.  Have the pch include as much of the VCL and standard library as you can.

You won't get as fast as Eclipse, but it will get better. Other than that, upgrade to XE3 if you can.

If you are having issues as you type, increase the timeout of code insight from 0ms to 250ms, then it will not kill your flow.

Comment: I did have issues when typing and just disabled the auto feature :) Since it is so slow, I only use it when I need it. Thx and for the tips.